# Can HotModuleReplacement run on different url? / instead of /webpack-dev-server/?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server

We are working a lot with react and hot module replacement and it is a pleasure to work with. But how can I start HotModuleReplacement in the bundle by default when someone accesses / or any other url?

I want to change the behavior and "remove" the "/webpack-dev-server/" during development. For Deployment we have a webpack.config without the hot module but what are the reasons to have the extra "/webpack-dev-server/" url?

The reasons are not as important as my original question: How do you change this behavior?